# how to use android delay not extending or implementing Thread or Runnable

Tags: android, timer, delay

i am new here and i want to know how to use delay in android without using Threading .
I am using  Handler

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
Thread r=new Thread () {
    public void run() {
        // Your next task
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(r, 30000);
```

Comment: `it does not work for me` can u explain more

Comment: @Nilu didn't understand what you are trying to say??

Comment: @Makacino please check my ans.

Comment: can u explain more about your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Thread r = new Thread with Runnable`

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
            Runnable r=new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Your next task
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(r, 30000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Your next task
    }
}, 30000);
```